# Who knows, how to configure bitbucket server, that was similar to bitbucket.org

Tags: git, bitbucket-server

Who knows, how to configure bitbucket server, that was similar to bitbucket.org

Once installed on the bitbucket server (the latest version), is different next:

1. Different repository creation window (bitbucket.org have advanced settings, and have imports from the repository)
2. Different file viewer (they have the opportunity to edit)
3. Different Pull-Request, our pull-requests are not seen in smartgithg (maybe a tick in the configuration, to give pull-requests?)
4. In the pull-request is not possible to click **approve**, only **merge**

Maybe I need to install additional plug-ins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a Product Manager at Atlassian. The Server and Cloud editions of Bitbucket have different histories and tech stacks, so some of the features are a bit different. You should find that you can achieve the same core benefits with code hosting, access management, and collaborative reviews via pull requests. Over time we expect to close more of the feature gaps you're seeing.

Addressing your specific questions...

1. We are working on an import facility for Server similar to Cloud
2. There's a [paid add-on](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.mohamicorp.stash.plugin.editor-for-stash/server/overview) for in-browser edit. We expect to add this functionality as core at some point.
3. There is SmartGit integration for Bitbucket Server, I suspect you'll need to configure it
4. You can approve a pull request if you are listed as a reviewer. If the pull request author hasn't added you, you can easily add yourself in [more recent versions](https://blog.bitbucket.org/2016/04/07/get-to-master-faster-with-pull-requests-in-bitbucket-server/)